# how to change language of date format?

Tags: python

I have parsed a Russian date format as a string:

16 август 2021 which is 16 august 2021

I need to transfor it into a normal date stamp as: 2021-08-16

I've tried something like this:

```
date = 16 август 2021
from babel.dates import format_datetime
import datetime
format_datetime(date, locale='en_US')
```

but it does not work.

How can I do it?

Comment: `format_datetime` expects to receive a `datetime` instance, not a string. You'll want to try to *parse* the string to a `datetime` first: http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/dates.html#babel.dates.parse_date

Comment: How are your code supposed to know that август is august? I would make dictionary where I would assign values of months in russian to their english equivalents or nummerical equivalents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`setlocale()` to `ru_RU`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) to parse dates with Russian names for months, weekdays, am/pm, etc.

> [`setlocale()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) is not thread-safe on most systems.

And then use the correct [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) with [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```py
from datetime import datetime
import locale

date = '16 август 2021'
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU')
d = datetime.strptime(date, '%d %B %Y')
print(repr(d))  # datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 16, 0, 0)
print(d)  # 2021-08-16 00:00:00
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')  # setlocale to the system default once done
```

And as [@deceze mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447684/how-to-change-language-of-date-format/70448802#comment124530344_70447684), you should be parsing the date-string to create a datetime obj, not creating a new string from the string you already have. If you need that, do that as the next step.

```py
# using `d` above
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')  # en for me
print(datetime.strftime(d, '%d %B %Y'))  # 16 August 2021
```